# Can't Install freetds php-mssql on Centos7

Tags: php, sql-server, centos7, freetds

I am at my wits end... Newbie to Linux... please help me...

Goal is to connect to MS SQL Server 2005 using PHP. I have installed PHP and ODBC. I am running CentOS7.

```
PHP Version => 5.4.16
```

.... (from php -i) ....

```
odbc

ODBC Support => enabled
```

I am running into 2 dependency issues when trying to install freetds and php-mssql extension. (see below)

```
[root@localhost freetds-dev.0.92.377]# yum install php-mssql freetds
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.supremebytes.com
 * epel: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: ftp.osuosl.org
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package freetds.x86_64 0:0.91-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit) for package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit) for package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-mssql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mssql-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mssql-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mssql-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (@updates)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
Error: Package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mssql-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (@updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have libgnutls.so version 28 though

```
/usr/lib64/libgnutls.so.28
/usr/lib64/libgnutls.so.28.20.4
```

I have been trying to figure this out for 4 days and I am very frustrated. Any help would be super appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed the EPEL repository for EL6, but you are running EL7. Remove it and try again with the correct EPEL version.

Comment: Ok just removed (yum remove epel-release) and installed (yum install epel-release)
`Installed:
  epel-release.noarch 0:7-5` but still same result.

Comment: I think my inexperience has led me to reinstall the wrong thing. Googling your suggestion now.

Comment: So now I have EPEL 7-5 installed (for Linux 7). Running the `yum install php-mssql freetds` still produces the same dependency issues. Is there anything you can think of I should be doing (or doing wrong). Thanks again for the help.

Comment: That's not very likely, unless you've done something to your system other than what you've already said. I suggest you start over.

Comment: Thank you, finally got this working, I used `yum remove epel-release` `rpm --rebuilddb` then `yum install epel-release`